# Hive creating a table but getting FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10035]: Column repeated in partitioning columns

Tags: hadoop, hive

Here is the code I am using to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE vi_vb(cTime STRING, VI STRING, Vital STRING, VB STRING)
PARTITIONED BY(cTime STRING, VI STRING)
CLUSTERED BY(VI) SORTED BY(cTime) INTO 32 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '1'
    COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '2'
    MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '3'
STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE;
```

I don't really know what the problem is, does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 27):

Partition by columns should not be in create table definition. Partition by columns will be automatically added to table columns.

Comment: Wasn't clear to me -solution simply remove cTime STRING, VI STRING from the create table

Comment: And how will it know which column number it is? I have 3 columns C1,C2,C3, and I say create table T(Y1 int, Y3 int) partitioned by Y2; how will it know which one I want for Y2 (there are 3 possibilities)? This doesn't make any effing sense...

Comment: You're supposed to use the Hive format in the path of your S3 files (e.g., <bucketname>/<some folder path>/year=2022/month=01/day=12/yourfile.parquet). Then define the year, month and day as your partitions. Then run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE <your table name>` to add those 3 new partitions to the metastore. This partition names will be used to inspect your path and figure out how to physically data are organized so not all files need to be scanned when the WHERE uses any partition. More about this at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

The columns "cTime, VI" are defined both as a normal column and as well as partitioning columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE vi_vb(Vital STRING, VB STRING)
PARTITIONED BY(cTime STRING, VI STRING)
CLUSTERED BY(VI) SORTED BY(cTime) INTO 32 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '1'
    COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '2'
    MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '3'
STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE;
```

Comment: It's good practice on StackOverflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work.